# Closure Compiler - obfuscate public methods - inconsistent behavior?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, google-closure-compiler

I just started using Closure Compiler, and I'm seeing some inconsistent behavior regarding obfuscation of public object methods.

I'm using `grunt-closure-compiler` - here's my grunt config:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        'closure-compiler': {
            app: {
                closurePath: 'closure-compiler',
                js: 'src/app.js',
                jsOutputFile: 'js/app.min.js',
                maxBuffer: 500,
                options: {
                    compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
                    language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
                    formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT'
                }
            }
        }
    });


    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-closure-compiler');

};
```

And here's `app.js` the file I want to obfuscate:

```
(function() {
  /**
   * @constructor
   */
  function MyClass() {
    var map = {};
    this.put = function(name, val) {
      map[name] = val;
    };
    this.get = function(name) {
      return map[name];
    };
  }
  var mapper = new MyClass();
  mapper.put("first", 123);
  alert(mapper.get("first"));

})();

(function() {
  /**
   * @constructor
   */
  function Foo() {
    var private_member_1 = 'bla';

    this.someMethod = function(param1, param2) {
      // do some stuff
      console.log('abc');
      return private_member_1;
    };
    // etc...
  }

  var foo = new Foo();
  var value = foo.someMethod();
  console.log(value + value);
})();
```

And this is the output after running `grunt closure-compiler:app`

```
'use strict';(function() {
  var a = new function() {
    var a = {};
    this.put = function(b, c) {
      a[b] = c;
    };
    this.get = function(b) {
      return a[b];
    };
  };
  a.put("first", 123);
  alert(a.get("first"));
})();
(function() {
  var a = (new function() {
    this.a = function() {
      console.log("abc");
      return "bla";
    };
  }).a();
  console.log(a + a);
})();
```

Notice that in the first closure the methods `put` and `get` were not obfuscated, while in the second closure the method `someMethod` **was** obfuscated.

Why does this happen? And how can I cause all public methods in all of my classes (like `put` and `get`) to be obfuscated as well?

Please note -

- I am willing to use a different tool other than Closure Compiler to achieve this.
- I want to use this with TypeScript, i.e. obfuscate the compiled TypeScript code, this is why I have many public methods.
- Some specific methods are API methods that should not be obfuscated. So I need a way to tell the obfuscator which methods to skip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

As of the 20150315 release of Closure-compiler, the type based optimizations are enabled by default.

---

This is actually covered in the project [FAQ](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#some-of-my-properties-are-getting-renamed-but-some-arent-why).

The option you want is `use_types_for_optimization`. This will enable property renaming even if a property of the same name is defined on an unrelated object.

The comprehensive list of properties which can only be renamed with this flag is huge: any property name defined on any object in an extern file.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - `get` and `put` are considered reserved words, and closure compiler ignores them on purpose.
I ran across a list of these reserved words earlier, but I can't find it now... would appreciate if someone posts a link to the complete list.